# iTunes connect build number issue

Tags: xcode, build, app-store-connect

I have a (I guess) simple question: Where do I change the build number in iTunes Connect / Xcode to make sure they are consistent.

I tried to upload an archive and got the error that the app was uploaded but the build number was different from the one in iTunes connect. And I am wondering where I entered the number. Apparently I entered Build 1 although in Xcode I was working on build 20something. So where do I change this because I cannot go back to build 1 in Xcode, than I get an error while uploading that the build is smaller than the previous transmitted.

I should add that this is the first time I upload an app and I am happy that got to this point :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version number in Xcode and the version number on iTunesConnect should be same. As shown in below images.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Whenever you upload new build for same version just increment build number. If you want to upload new version then you need to change version number as well as build number in Xcode. But this version number should match with version number on iTunesConnect.

Comment: Thanks. So I understand that everytime I just change the Build Number I can just upload the archive to iTunes Connect. When I change the Version number I have to click on "version or platform" and enter the new version number (from Xcode) before I upload the new archive?